# Why is Wordpress mangling my Tamil titles?

Tags: php, unicode, character-encoding

I use wordpress 3.0.1 for blogging.  If I post am article in other languages (like Tamil), the title of the post is displayed as junk characters.  The same characters appear in links to the post.

For example, if my title is "அம்மா அம்மா அம்மா அம்மா" the link is displayed as

```
e0%ae%85%e0%ae%ae%e0%af%8d%e0%ae%ae%e0%ae%be-%e0%ae%85%e0%ae%ae%e0%af%8d%e0%ae%ae%e0%ae%be-%e0%ae%85%e0%ae%ae%e0%af%8d%e0%ae%ae%e0%ae%be-%e0%ae%85%e0%ae%ae%e0%af%8d%e0%ae%ae%e0%ae%be/
```

What is going on and how do I fix it?

Comment: Those aren't junk characters, they're your title... misencoded.

Comment: ok can to say a solution to encode it properly

Comment: Those are the HTMLEntities of your title, since URLs don't support those characters<I don't think they do, correct me if I'm wrong>. See [RFC-1738](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html).

Comment: Not without knowing how you're getting it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and hope it works [WordPress Plug-in for Writing in 8 Indian languages](http://www.monusoft.com/Products/WordPressPlugin.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Browsers like chrome automatically display urldecoded values of links when hovering, but your browser might not ([Older firefox, IE..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sD7F.png)). Anyway it's working correctly. For example, if you go to this wikipedia page:

`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%e0%ae%85%e0%ae%ae%e0%af%8d%e0%ae%ae%e0%ae%be-%e0%ae%85%e0%ae%ae%e0%af%8d%e0%ae%ae%e0%ae%be-%e0%ae%85%e0%ae%ae%e0%af%8d%e0%ae%ae%e0%ae%be-%e0%ae%85%e0%ae%ae%e0%af%8d%e0%ae%ae%e0%ae%be/`

You can see that wikipedia detected it as `அம்மா-அம்மா-அம்மா-அம்மா`, but your browser might still show the percent encoding in the url.

It's not clear but if you mean that you see the percent encoding actually on the html  page as well, then that's a mishandling in your code or wordpress's code.

By the way, I assumed your mispasted your question and left out the first `%` (it starts with `e0%ae%85..`, even though it should be `%e0%ae%85..`), if the first `%` is also actually left out then that might be the issue.